# Launching issue Unreal engine4 editor

Tags: macbook, macros

I just install Unreal engine 4.13. But i am facing issue when i try to launch it.

At very first time when i launched unreal editor it opened two
instance and my mac was hang completely after that i tried four or
five time to reopen it again but every time it was stuck.

I completely shutdown my MacBook and start again but still have the same problem. Every time when i launched it stuck on 35%.

Answer (score 0):

Well i got the solution now. This is boot file problem.so for correcting it i
Close epic game launcher first then open

> user../library/application support/epic/UnrealEngine/4.13/DevicedDAtaCache/

Then delete all file specially

> Boot.ddc